# NSSstring encoding not found

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I download an html page and I try to encode it from NSData to NSString with this:

```
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
```

I found that it gives a text with strange chars.
I found that the page is look ok in the browser in

WINDOWS-1255
ISO-8858-8

Does it exist an encoding in objective-c that support it ?

Comment: There is no ISO-8858-8, it should be ISO-8859-8.

Comment: [Windows-1255](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255) refers to Hebrew character encoding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSString` does not support `Windows Hebrew` character encoding.
`CFString` fortunately does support `Windows Hebrew` character encoding.

Use `CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding()` to convert the `CFStringEncoding` to `NSStringEncoding`, for example:

```
  NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding (kCFStringEncodingWindowsHebrew)];
```

Answer (score 0):

If Anne's answer doesnt work (although it probably will), try with `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding` which is equiv to WinLatin1:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receivedData encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
```

---

According to the [`NSString` Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJJAICE):

> ```
> NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding
> ```
>
> Microsoft Windows codepage 1252; equivalent to WinLatin1.