# Read string from a file return nil

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring

I try to read string from a file with :

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dirty" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&err];
```

And the string i get is nil. in the error i get :

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=261 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 261.)" UserInfo=0x21063410 {NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Applications/78889F89-B83C-480C-A246-999152EE757C/Myapp.app/dirty.txt, NSStringEncoding=4}
```

Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: Try to use another encoding, i.e. `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

Comment: The text file is in hebrew

Comment: `Cocoa error 261` is `NSFileReadInapplicableStringEncodingError` which means the encoding of file is different than what you are passing in tge API.

Comment: Maybe you could try NSUnicodeStringEncoding

Comment: Amar is right, the problem comes from the file encoding. Check which encoding you used when creating the file and change it in you call

Comment: Thanks Amar it was the problem

Comment: @Amar : post that as answer (might be with more details) so that this question gets marked as accepted...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, `Cocoa error 261` is [`NSFileReadInapplicableStringEncodingError`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW6) which means the encoding of file is different than what you are passing in the API.

For Hebrew language encoding, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8144325/1407017)

```
NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(kCFStringEncodingWindowsHebrew) error:&err];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The error seems to be the Encoding Issue ..

If you don't know the encoding of your file, you could try this method:

```
- (id)initWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

Refer [HERE](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSString/stringWithContentsOfFile%3ausedEncoding%3aerror%3a)

And 
Try Something like this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSStringEncoding encoding;

NSString *my_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url
                                                 usedEncoding:&encoding 
                                                        error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:nil error:&err];
```

or change the type of "encoding" hope it will solve you problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
NSString *pathtest = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"dirty" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString* content = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathtest encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
NSLog(@"Test: %@",content);
```